# In a try to fix NSRangeException error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've caught an error:

> Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
>   *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1330 beyond bounds [0 .. 1329]

At string

```
NSArray *currentABRecords = [ApplicationPhoneDirectory records];
```

`ApplicationPhoneDirectory` is `NSObject` with unique contacts (dict and array).

But I think the error is about working with memory, how can I manage it more properly to avoid appearance of such a problem?

Or, in case if I'm incorrect I can put `records` part in there.

upd:

```
static NSArray *RecordsForABInterval(UInt32 start, UInt32 end, CFArrayRef allPeople) {
    NSMutableArray *peoples = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(end - start) * 2];
    for (int i = (int) start; i < end; i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
        NSString *firstName = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
        NSString *lastName = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
        NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                              firstName.length > 0 ? firstName : @"",
                              lastName.length > 0 ? lastName : @""];
        fullName = [fullName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneList = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        CFIndex phonesCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneList);
        for (int j = 0; j < phonesCount; ++j) {
            CFTypeRef ABphone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneList, j);
            NSString *phone = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABphone);
            NSString *phoneInSMFormat = [phone phoneNumberInSMFormat];
            if ([phoneInSMFormat isValidSMPhoneNumber]) {
                    NSDictionary *record = @{
                                             @"name" : fullName,
                                             @"phone" : phoneInSMFormat,
                                             @"original" : phone
                                             };
                [peoples addObject:record];
            }
        }
        if (phoneList != NULL) {
            CFRelease(phoneList);
        }
    }
    return peoples;
}

+ (NSArray *)records {
    const int MaxAutoreleaseStep = 500;
    NSMutableArray *records = [NSMutableArray array];
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                accessGranted = granted;
            });
        });
    } else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // The user has previously given access, add the contact
        accessGranted = YES;
    }
    else {
        // The user has previously denied access
        // Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings app
        if (addressBook != NULL) {
            CFRelease(addressBook);
        }

        return nil;
    }

    // TODO: review this logic - should it be a single call to AB?
    if (addressBook != NULL) {
        CFRelease(addressBook);
    }

    if (accessGranted) {
        ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
        if (error != NULL) {
            if (addressbook != NULL) {
                CFRelease(addressbook);
            }
            return nil;
        }

        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressbook);
        CFIndex peopleCount = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressbook);
        for (int start = 0; start < peopleCount; start += MaxAutoreleaseStep) {
            @autoreleasepool {
                int end = start + MaxAutoreleaseStep;
                NSArray *contactListCut = RecordsForABInterval((UInt32) start, (UInt32) MIN((int)peopleCount, end), allPeople);
                [records addObjectsFromArray:contactListCut];
            }
        }

        if (allPeople != NULL) {
            CFRelease(allPeople);
        }
        if (addressbook != NULL) {
            CFRelease(addressbook);
        }
    }

    return records;
}
```

upd2:

```
- (NSString *)phoneNumberInSMFormat {
    NSString *phone = [self numericPresentation];
    if (phone.length > 0 && [phone characterAtIndex:0] == '8') {
        NSMutableString *modifiedString = [phone mutableCopy];
        [modifiedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@"7"];
        phone = modifiedString;
    }
    return phone;
}
- (BOOL)isValidSMPhoneNumber {
    static NSCharacterSet *characterSet = nil;
    if (characterSet == nil) {
        characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    }
    if ([self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet].location != NSNotFound) {
        return NO;
    }
    if (self.length < 7 || self.length > 12) {
        return NO;
    }

    return [self characterAtIndex:0] != '8';
}
```

Comment: the error is self explained, you are accessing an array with an index out of the array bounds, so, we need you to show us the part you are accessing this array to start analysing the issue

Comment: @thxou sure, updated my post

Comment: FYI - The old AddressBook framework has been deprecated since iOS 9.0. You should be using the newer Contacts framework.

Comment: Just in case if you have not made up your mind to switch to newer contact frameworks, could you please tell at which line it is crashing by putting the Exception breakpoint, also it would be plus if you paste this two methods  [phone phoneNumberInSMFormat] and [phoneInSMFormat isValidSMPhoneNumber],

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan it starts from `NSArray *currentABRecords = [ApplicationPhoneDirectory records];` and finally crashes at `ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);` (updated post with methods you've asked to review)

Comment: NSArray *contactListCut = RecordsForABInterval((UInt32) start, (UInt32) MIN((int)peopleCount, end), allPeople); 

You are sending in the minimum value MIN((int)peopleCount, end). try sending the peopleCount directly.

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan like this? `NSArray *contactListCut = RecordsForABInterval((UInt32) start, (UInt32) ((void)((int)peopleCount), end), allPeople);` About arrays - Ill check it at evening and post results

Comment: Try this, NSArray *contactListCut = RecordsForABInterval((UInt32) start, (UInt32) peopleCount, allPeople);  also i would require value for "end" and allpeople count

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan after last changes "end" becomes unused value, "allpeople" is `CFArrayRef` with (in my case) 6 NSObject elements, just as you can see in my code.